# How to get time difference relative to official business hour

Tags: java

I have to show total working hour of employee  relative to official business hour.
if a task is started then start time and end time entered in to database.

Entry something like:

```
start time= `2013-10-18 16:06:16.840`
end time=`2013-10-22 16:09:09.760`
```

Working hour is configurable as per organization.

**working hour=** `7.45 (7 hour and 45 minutes) =1 day`

if someone is worked more then working hour, It consider under extra work and consider as extra time.

I need output according to user worked for a day. Output for one day like

```
7.45  hour then 1 days 
7.50 hour then 1 days and 5 minute
14.50 hour then 1 days, 7 hour and 5 minutes
```

I have done below coding. It is not giving as much as acurate result of my expect.

What I done:

```
1) take difference of two days
2) instead of using 24 hour, I used business hour.
```

**Code:**

```
 public static long[] getTimeDifference(Date d1,Date d2,int holiday,String businessHour)
    {
    long hour=0;
     if(businessHour.indexOf(".")!=-1)
     {
     hour=Long.valueOf(businessHour.substring(0,businessHour.indexOf(".")));///check for hour
     }
     else
     {
     hour=Long.valueOf(businessHour);
     }
     long[] time=new long[3];
     long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
                     
     //double diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
     long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
     long diffHours =  (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % hour);
     long diffDays =   (diff / (hour * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    diffDays=diffDays-holiday;
     time[0]=diffDays;
     time[1]=diffHours;
     time[2]=diffMinutes;
                     
     return time;
    }
```

**output:**
11 days: 05 hours: 02 minutes

I am not included minute logic yet, how can I do implementation? I don't have idea. I am confuse with this.

Comment: Why are you using `Long` as a datatype for your business hours ? That way you loose the decimal fraction part of the input String.

Comment: You cannot calculate how many hours he worked each day if you only have the time he entered on friday and the time he leaves today.

Comment: @user2310289 for weekend I have different logic.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter as I mention in question. fot minute, I have not written any code yet.

Comment: don't forget to do some handling for timezones, daylight saving times, additional seconds added as correction, etc. Be careful when using java.util.Date or the calendar classes. The new DateTime API introduced in Java 8 is much better than the current date APIs in the JDK

Answer (score 0):

To get the days, minutes and seconds that have passed between both dates, you can do this:

```
    long hour = 0;
    if (businessHour.indexOf(".") != -1) {
        hour = Long.valueOf(businessHour.substring(0,
            businessHour.indexOf(".")));// /check for hour
    } else {
        hour = Long.valueOf(businessHour);
    }
    long[] time = new long[3];
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

    // double diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;

    double diffDays = (diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    double diffHours = (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000)) - diffDays*24;
    double diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) - (diffDays*24 + diffHours) * 60;

    time[0] = diffDays;
    time[1] = diffHours;
    time[2] = diffMinutes;
```

But i don't know if it is what you want.